# How I can collect live data about football matches?

Tags: php, database, web

I wonder about the ways of collecting live data about football matches like: scores, players, events (yellow, red cards, injuries).

I know that there is possibility of taking this data from pages like FlashScores using PHP, however I want to know how the FlashScores and similar services gets data to their databases. What way they collect data?

It is impossible to have person on each match :P

I wonder if they get scores from web pages of each league. Is it possible? If it doesn't generate too big network traffic?

If anyone has some ideas, please help me with this problem ;)

Comment: Even if Stackoverflow isn't the place to ask such questions, I think it would be quite interesting to hear some good answers on it.

Comment: *It is impossible to have person on each match* that's where your wrong, FlashScores most likely doesn't have a person at every match, but there are always people at every match, keeping scores, I believe [Stats](https://www.stats.com/data-feeds/) are actually connected to most sports scoreboards and so can get scores almost instantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Companies like Opta indeed had (at least) 2 persons per match in the major football leagues to label events in football matches. One watched the game and announced the events to the other, who wrote them down (in a program that is optimized for that).
Recently they changed their procedure to [3 persons](http://www.optasports.com/about/how-we-do-it/the-data-collection-process.aspx):
 'Three expert analysts will cover each match, one collecting all of the home team actions, one the away team and a third analyst checking the data for consistency and adding additional layers of data.' 


Doing this on your own seems like a pretty extensive idea. Afaik there is a lot of research going on, trying to automate this labeling process from videos alone.

As a side note: 1899 Hoffenheim, as an example, use sensors in shoes and balls, as well as multiple cameras (and even drones) to collect live training data automatically. But up to now, sensors are forbidden in all major football leagues I know.

Comment: http://www.optasports.com/ - I've built a few solutions based on OPTA data; it's super detailed, and really expensive as it's aimed at broadcasters and media outlets, rather than independent web projects. Here's a list of all their feeds: http://www.optasports.com/services/media/data-feeds/core-data-feeds.aspx